# The local variable xxx is never read

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

```
boolean startGameBoolean;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
extras.getInt("startGameBoolean");
if (startGameBoolean = true){
    counter.start();
}
```

Eclipse gives a warning that "The local variable startGameBoolean is never read"; but it is.
I get the boolean from an another intent.

**I edited my code, I missed some of it, sorry!**

Comment: I dont understand you. But you get the second startGameBoolean as a string (between "" ). and it is better to use getBoolean method to get boolean.

Comment: Have you written something wrong because startGameBoolean really is never used...

Comment: Is there more code that you can show us? Or are those the only three lines of code?

Comment: It may also help to re-phrase your text into a question; it's difficult to tell what exactly you're *asking* here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `startGameBoolean = extras.getBoolean("startGameBoolean");`?

in the code you gave, `boolean startGameBoolean;` is not used anywhere. the warning means that although you declared it, it is not used in the block where it lives, therefore could (should) be removed.

**Edit:**

After seeing your addition, you use `startGameBoolean`, but you assign to it, while you should compare to it:

```
if (startGameBoolean == true){
//                    ^
    counter.start();
}
```

Also, assign the result of `getBoolean()` to the variable as I wrote in the first statement.

Comment: Better yet: `if (startGameBoolean)`. It's already a boolean, no need for `== true` (and it introduces the possibility of the very error the OP made).

Answer (score 5):

I would venture to agree with Eclipse, it's not being used. The code you've show us doesn't have it being used anywhere.

**Update**

The variable is still never used because you **assign** it in your `if` condition; you never compare it (which is what it looks like you're trying to do).

Change

```
if (startGameBoolean = true){
```

to

```
if (startGameBoolean){
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (startGameBoolean = true){
```

Should be..

```
if (startGameBoolean == true){
```

..or better still..

```
if (startGameBoolean){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean startGameBoolean = extras.getBoolean("startGameBoolean");
```

Something like this? You cant fetch `boolean` with `getInt()`. Perhaps, if you are dealing with int but with values `0` and `1`. Then you should change the type of `startGameBoolean` to `int` and fetch it with `getInt()`, people do this sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

**I had this same problem developing for Android.**

The reason you're seeing those warnings saying the "variable is never read" is because you're assigning it **RIGHT AFTER** creating it.  Try creating the variable at the start of the class, then assigning it in an OnCreate() or other appropriate method that gets called when the class is first created.

Answer (score 0):

***I had a similar error***... for this line

> `JLabel label = new JLabel("You have $" + amountInAccount + " in your account.");`

*I used **Quick fix (Ctrl+1)** and chose **Remove 'label', keep side-effect assignments...***

and the code became

> `new JLabel("You have $" + amountInAccount + " in your account.");`